# Identification of vector spaces via a choice of basis and naturality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

My understanding of natural transformations (also called canonical?) is the following:

We need two functors given, say $F_1$ and $F_2$, with $F_{1,2}:\mathbf{K}\to \mathbf{L}$, $\mathbf{K}$ and $\mathbf{L}$ categories. Then a natural transformation is an assignment $\tau : F_1 \to F_2$, which assigns to each object of $\mathbf{K}$, an $\mathbf{L}$ morphism, namely
$$
\tau V: F_1(V)\to F_2(V),
$$
but in such a manner that the following holds: Given **any** $\mathbf{K}$-morphism $f:K_1 \to K_2$, the appropriate diagram commutes:
$$
F_2(f)\circ \tau K_1 = \tau K_2 \circ F_1(f).
$$

> Identifying an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, via a choice of basis
>   $$
> L_a: \mathbb{R}^n \to V , \ \ \mathbf{x}\mapsto \sum_{i\in I}x_ia_i\in V
> $$
>   with $a_i(i\in I)$ a basis for $V$, gives me the sense that it is **not** canonical. Is it easy to should that it is not canonical by working with the naturality definition in the category **Vect**?

Comment: Well the first question you'd need to answer is what functors is $L_a$ supposed to be a putative natural transformation between?

Comment: Any hints? Is it obvious?

Comment: One functor should be the identity functor $F_1: V \mapsto V$, the other should be a functor $F_2: V\mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ that somehow maps a vector space to $\mathbb{R}^n$ to which it is isomorphic to?